# python program to divide numbers in file in selected order

Tags: python, file-io

I am new to Python and wanted to read a file, which has even count of numbers, (say 20) numbers like

```
100
200 
59
78
...
590
13
```

I want to read them and compute division result of `val[11]/val[1], val[12]/val[2]` etc. Would you please help me. Or any other language you could suggest where it would be fast. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Have you made any effort to do this yourself?

Comment: Thanks. I don't know python and wanted to use that. I searched internet and SO, but could not get answer.

Comment: Is this homework? I ask because the answer you get will vary based on that.

Comment: Thanks. No, it is not homework

Comment: You "searched the internet" and couldn't find a python tutorial that would teach you the very basics you need to know to do simple math problems like this?

Comment: @Recursed Actually the type of division intended is little unusual. Thanks for your comment

Comment: I mean, its really not. Applying an operation using two values in a list? This is a very basic computer science problem, and I'm sure you could find what you need from ANY basic python tutorial.

Comment: Seriously, this is a simple program. Search for how to load a file into a list of strings, then search for how to iterate through a list. Come to SO when you have some code and a specific problem with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, this will get you ***just started*** with the basics, ***but* you'll have to figure out the logic of your math, the various index values, and order of operations** to solve your problem.

This simply opens a file and displays its contents. The data is read as strings, and converted to floats so that you can do math with the numbers.

I strongly recommend you read a [Python tutorial](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/), or *better yet* work in a programming language you are <strike>more</strike> familiar with.

```
with open('data.txt') as f:
    data = f.readlines()
    for i in range(len(data)):
        result = float(data[i])
        print result
```

Contents of `data.txt`

```
100
200 
59
78
590
13
```

***The rest is up to you.*** Please feel free to come back and ask for help when you get stuck with a specific problem.

Finally, since the data from the file ends up in a variable name `data` which is a Python [list](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#list), reading through these [Python docs](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/introduction.html#lists) and this [tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_lists.htm) should be helpful in understanding this data structure.

Comment: Sad that this needed to be posted on SO, happy that you didn't give him this simple program on a silver platter. :)

Comment: @Recursed Agreed .. and I wasn't even sure if I should post this much.. but I guess this is the fairly trivial/mechanical part .. OP will have to figure out the logic and order of operations.

Comment: I think you answered in the best way possible, +1 for giving a response that may actually benefit the OP. Hopefully he takes your advice and explores the Python tutorials.

Comment: @Recursed Thanks for saying that .. I really was somewhat conflicted about this.

Comment: I'm just glad someone didn't come along and give him the answer, maybe this will push him to learn!

Comment: @Recursed Maybe this should have been treated as a homework question and answered accordingly. No code. Just the way things should be done, and links to docs and/or tutorials...

Comment: @user984260 I added some additional links to my answer, I hope they will be useful to you.

Comment: @Levon Accepted all of your advice, not just the content of the answer

Comment: @user984260 Ok, glad to hear that .. Python is a great language, and relatively easy to learn compared to some others, so I hope once you are a bit more comfortable with Python/programming you'll come back with questions (and answers for other users too). Good luck